# Unit tests for cloud Bigtable data access

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, scalatest, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

How can I get a mock Bigtable with some data to be used in unit testing (ScalaTest with MockitoSugar)? I'm creating an API on top of the Hbase java API, and the data access involves forming row keys using custom logic and then used in Get or Scan methods. So its not enough to have a Result mock object, instead I need a Table instance with some rows in it. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure this would count as "unit testing", but there is a Bigtable emulator that lets you test against an in-memory implementation of the service:
https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/emulator

You can also run it in a docker container:
https://github.com/spotify/docker-bigtable/issues/2#issuecomment-275779862

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I also don't think that it qualifies as unit test, but it will be useful in the development.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this is an HBase question more than a Cloud Bigtable question.  Here are [the HBase testing docs](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#unit.tests).  I use the HBase minicluster to have a fully formed local Hadoop/HBase environment.